# Split folders based on subfolders names

Tags: php, windows, synology

For a website I have a lot of folders containing the same subfolders (images + thumbnails). All of them contain the "images" folder, but not all of them contain "thumbnails" folder.

```
/directory1
   /folder1
      /images
      /thumbnails
   /folder2
      /images
   /folder3
      /images
      /thumbnails
   /folderA
      /images
   /folderB
      /images
      /thumbnails
```

I would like to move the thumbnails into another directory, so basically separate the folderstructure:

```
/directory1
   /folder1
      /images
   /folder2
      /images
   /folder3
      /images
   /folderA
      /images
   /folderB
      /images

/directory2
   /folder1
      /thumbnails
   /folder3
      /thumbnails
   /folderB
      /thumbnails
```

Is there an easy/fast way to do this?

All folders/files are stored on a Synology NAS and I can access them via a Windows PC.

Comment: is your question about how to access those files with php or about the logic to split when you already have access to those files?

Comment: I only have to do this once, so it's more about the logic to split them. I know it will be possible with a php-script, but I'm interested in a more easy solution (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved it with a little php-script. The main functions used are:

1. `ini_set('max_execution_time', 10800);` to give it some to run if necessary
2. `scandir` to check all files and folders within a directory
3. `mkdir` to create a new directory elsewhere
4. `rename` to move the file or folder to the new directory

At first I was concerned that the `rename` function would copy the files/folders and delete the old ones afterwards, which would take a lot of time. But this is not the case, it moves the files/folders and it ran actually very fast.